# Deleting the content of Google appengine project

Tags: google-app-engine

i made an Google Appengine Project but i realized that i dont really need it. I have pushed the source codes there several times , and i want to delete them from the appengine forever but i want to keep the Project in the google console.

**So what i did is:** i have deleted all the versions , but the one (the last one) is still there and cant be deleted and it says you cannot delete a version with traffic share so i have pushed clear **app.yaml** file and clear **index.php** file

**Now my final question is**: are all the source codes **deleted**? or they are still somewhere ? how can i make sure myself that they are gone forever from google appengine?

Thanks.

Comment: did you remove images for docker registry also?

Comment: i have no idea what it is

Comment: there are special bucket when you're using Flexible VM - https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/artifacts.%APPID%.appstpo.com which contains docker images of your app

Answer (score 3):

There're two places where your app code is stored:

1. App Engine version. You can remove it using console and replace last version with an empty one, as you already did
2. for Flexible VM there is a special Storage bucket for temporary docker images under https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser, such as:

   - artifacts.APPID.appspot.com
   - staging.APPID.appspot.com
   - vm-config.APPID.appspot.com
   - vm-containers.APPID.appspot.com

That's all, as far as I know. But don't think anybody can give any guarantee, I believe that Google have some backup service for Cloud artifacts, so it's very likely that for some time it will keep a copy in their backups.

Comment: it contains Bucket which is clear , i probably dont understand

Comment: if it's clear, you're ok, you don't have anything here (just checked, PHP isn't based on Flexible VM, so it must be empty for you, that's ok)